# Selected Item from Observable collection in code Behind

Tags: c#

this subject is really frequent but I would like to understand and if possible get the solution. How can we listen to events coming from an item who had been selected from an observable collection in code behind.
I have written an example :

first the class Personne:

```
public class Personne : INotifyPropertyChanged{
    private int _age = 10;
    public int Age{
       get { return _age; }
       set { _age = value; OnPropertyChanged("Age");  }

       }

    private string _name="";
    public string Name
    {
       get { return _name;  }
       set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }

    }
    public Personne() { }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And now into the main class:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int indice = 0;
        ObservableCollection<Personne> _collection = new ObservableCollection<Personne>();
        _collection.CollectionChanged += _collection_CollectionChanged;
        _collection.Add(new Personne());            
        Personne tmp = _collection[indice];
        indice++;
        tmp.PropertyChanged += Tmp_personne_PropertyChanged;
        tmp.Age = indice;
        _collection.Add(new Personne());
        tmp = _collection[indice];
        indice++;
        tmp.Age = indice;




    }

    private static void _collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       int a =1;
        a++;

    }

    private static void Tmp_personne_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 1;
        a++;
    }
}
```

If we try it, the first

```
 Personne tmp = _collection[indice];
    indice++;
    tmp.PropertyChanged += Tmp_personne_PropertyChanged;
    tmp.Age = indice;
```

fires the event, but the second no. Why?

Comment: Your code example is not very clear, nor is your problem description. But if I understand correctly, you are asking why the `PropertyChanged` event is not raised at the second example of `tmp.Age = indice;`, while it is raised in the first. If that is correct, then the simple answer is that you just haven't subscribed to it. Which you could have determined yourself had you set a breakpoint in the `OnPropertyChanged()` method and stepped through the code. You'd have found that `handler` was `null` in that case, a clear signal that you haven't subscribed to the event.

Comment: Add another `tmp.PropertyChanged += Tmp_personne_PropertyChanged;` statement after getting the second `tmp` object, and the event will be raised, just like in the first example.'

Comment: In fact, the selected item could change dynamically everytime. So I only want to listen to the selecteditem egal on which items he is pointing.

Comment: In fact, subscribing directly to the `PropertyChanged` event probably isn't the right approach anyway. But there's not enough context in your question to get you headed back in the right direction.